# Three.js on IE, screen goes black when you zoom with mouse wheel

Tags: internet-explorer, three.js, mousewheel

I'm using Three.js which is fine on all other browsers, but goes black when using the mouse-wheel to zoom.

If I zoom the camera with other methods it's fine, and there's a zoom limit set so it shouln't be reaching the end of camera far etc.

```
function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {

    setZoom(camera.fov - event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05);

}


function setZoom(fov){

    camera.fov = fov;

    if(camera.fov < 30) camera.fov = 30;
    if(camera.fov > 100) camera.fov = 100;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}
```

Any ideas how to solve this particular IE bug?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. See my file here: http://packertest.com/HeapVis/HeapVoxel4.htmlworks great in Chrome, zoom makes everything blank in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, if your camera minimal and maximal viewing distance limits are enaught.
You can also change camera fov to camera move closer, (avoid of prblem with maximal wieving distance). `camera.transitionX(object.distance/5)`.